# ResponseListener in Symfony leads to duplicate header 'Content-Type' from apache in dev mode

Tags: php, apache, symfony, error-handling, mamp

I'm running a Symfony app on a MAMP PRO setup on a Mac. Within my symfony app I use a ResponseListener which contains the following function:

```
/**
 * Handle OPTIONS calls and add Access-Control headers.
 *
 * @param FilterResponseEvent $event Filter response event
 */
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    // Don't do anything if it's not the master request.
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($request->getRealMethod() == Request::METHOD_OPTIONS) {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, X-App-Version, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT');
        $event->setResponse($response);
    } else {
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, X-App-Version, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT');
    }
}
```

It's just a solution to develop a Ionic app in the browser and handle the OPTIONS calls from the app without getting errors there. But it's just an example, I have the same issue with other Symfony apps that use a ResponseListener.

The above example works perfectly if I run it in the `prod` environment or in the `dev` environment if no error occurs. But as soon as I get an PHP error it results in the following:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

If I look into the apache_error.log it says:

```
FastCGI: comm with server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.0.13.fcgi" aborted: error parsing headers: duplicate header 'Content-Type', referer: http://app.domain/app_dev.php/my-route
```

This only seems to happen for PHP errors. If I for example throw a `NotFoundHttpException` with

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException("Test exception");
```

I get the usual Symfony error page.

If I do something like

```
new ClassDoesNotExist();
```

it results in the Internal Server error.

I know that it is due to the ResponseListener because the Symfony error page is shown as soon as I put an `exit;` on the top of the function like this:

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    exit;

    // Don't do anything if it's not the master request.
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Is there something wrong with the ResponseListener? Is there some kind of configuration that can be done on apache that this error is not thrown?

EDIT:

Here is the MAMP PRO vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName project.localhost

DocumentRoot "/Users/MyUser/Projekte/MyProject/web"

<IfModule xsendfile_module>
    XSendFilePath "/Users/MyUser/Projekte/MyProject/web"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Users/MyUser/Projekte/MyProject/web">
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule authz_host_module>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess project.localhost processes=2 threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup project.localhost
WSGIScriptAlias /project.localhostWsgiApp "/Users/MyUser/Projekte/MyProject/web/wsgiapp.py"
AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
Action php-fastcgi "/fcgi-bin/php7.0.13.fcgi"
```

EDIT 2:

As suggested by @mickadoo it could be possible that another Listener is adding the duplicate header `Content-Type`. If I stop the propagation I get the Symfony error message I want. But my listener is also the first being called, so this would prevent any other listener from ever being triggered. Executing `debug:event-dispatcher` results in the following:

```
"kernel.response" event
-----------------------

 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Order   Callable                                                                                     Priority
 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
  #1      MyCompany\Bundle\AppBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse()                   0
  #2      Sonata\BlockBundle\Cache\HttpCacheHandler::onKernelResponse()                                0
  #3      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse()              0
  #4      Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelResponse()        0
  #5      Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse()              0
  #6      Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse()       0
  #7      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse()              -100
  #8      Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse()   -128
  #9      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse()           -1000
  #10     Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse()      -1024
 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------
```

When I add another response listener with priority -2048 to make him be the last one triggered and use the following method there:

```
/**
 * @param FilterResponseEvent $event Filter response event
 */
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    // Don't do anything if it's not the master request.
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    $response = $event->getResponse();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response->headers->all());
    exit;
}
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [cache-control] => Array
    (
        [0] => no-cache, private
    )
    [access-control-allow-origin] => Array
    (
        [0] => *
    )
    [access-control-allow-credentials] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
    [access-control-allow-headers] => Array
    (
        [0] => Origin, X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, X-App-Version, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
    )
    [access-control-allow-methods] => Array
    (
        [0] => POST, GET, PUT
    )
    [content-type] => Array
    (
        [0] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    )
    [x-debug-token] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2f5dbb
    )
    [x-debug-token-link] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://app.project.localhost/app_dev.php/_profiler/2f5dbb
    )
)
```

But there still is no additional `Content-Type`. Any ideas?

EDIT 3:

Another strange thing is the following:

If I use the `$event->stopPropagation()` at the end of my method and add the listener with priority 0 everything works (meaning the Symfony error page is shown), if I set it with priority -2048 I get the Apache error message. But even if I output all headers at the end of it there is no duplicate header. I don't really get how this is possible. How can there be multiple of the same header being returned to apache with just one request and all headers at the end are unique in the output?

Comment: Could you please attach the Apache VirtualHost configuration?

Comment: @sentenza It's the vhost config that MAMP PRO generates, I didn't change it but attached it to the original question.

Comment: I don't have the Symfony codebase open right now,but maybe it's another listener adding the headers. You could try `$event->stopPropagation()` at the end of your listener.

Comment: I tried and it works that way. Meaning I get the Symfony error page like I should. But my Listener is the first in the list if I run `debug:event-dispatcher`, so I would remove the execution of all the other response listeners in general.

Comment: @mickadoo I added additional information regarding the stopPropagation to the question.

Comment: It's strange alright, but if you just want it fixed you could always check in your listener if the 'Content-Type' header was set and if not then set it.

Comment: @mickadoo My listener does not set the Content-Type. That's the problem. Something else is setting it and I don't know where and how I can stop that. The only quick fix for know is to stop everything else from running, but that's not really a feasible solution.

Comment: I'm not sure it is just down to the listener. I created a new Symfony 3.2 project. I changed nothing except I added a listener with the same code as your own and added it to the services as a listener for `kernel.response`. I tested that it was being called and it was. I then did a GET request for the default controller but added `$x = new Blah();` to the controller. For both GET and OPTIONS requests I see an error page and no mention of the duplicate headers. Do you think it might be something else causing it?

Comment: Yeah it's possible that is has nothing to do with the listeners at all. I only know that it help's to stop the propagation, but this doesn't mean that it has to be because of the listeners. Any idea how I can figure out what the source of the problem is?

Comment: If you're using xdebug I would step through the request. You could add a breakpoint on a method that sets the response headers and see where the culprit is. I don't think I can do much more for you ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Check if something is manually calling `header()` and then it's called again by symfony, causing the overlap

Comment: I looked and nothing is calling `header()`. I will look with xdebug if I can find something.

Comment: You could try to fiddle with your listener's priority, setting it below one listener at a time and keep on doing that 'til you get the duplicate headers issue; you'll know which event added the extraneous header.

Comment: I already tried to set it as the last one and checked the headers but there was no duplicate header present. Is it possible that it has something to do with the fact that there is one error response and one separate from Symfony?

Comment: What symfony version do you use?

Comment: I use Symfony 3.2.3

Comment: Turn off error display. It sounds like the PHP error handler is trying to dump out it's text/HTML and setting the Content-Type to match. Meanwhile you are trying to set a content type for your output. Turn the PHP error display off and see if that fixes it.

Comment: The `display_errors` configuration is already set to `Off`. Or is there another relevant setting?

Comment: In case you haven't figured out the best way to check for this issue maybe it would be a good idea to make use of Go! AOP library which is PHP based and I want to believe there is a bundle for Symfony that manages its integration. If I am correct you can be able to create an aspect that monitors your call on the header function where ever it is called. This way you may be able to tell where header is being called. This would be nothing but a debugging approach

Comment: It could be that there is a custom error handler (set by set_error_handler()) for your php scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about set the response to the event?

I mean on the response given by $event->getResponse() you add the headers, but you don't $event->setResponse($response) on the else part.